# Minimum required NTFS permissions for roaming profiles

Tags: permissions, windows, roaming-profile

A earlier [question links](https://serverfault.com/questions/164109/server-2008-roaming-profiles-permissions) to this Microsoft document about [roaming profile permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737633(WS.10).aspx).  I want to know if you can lock the permissions down even further then what is recommended.  Do I really have to give users full control?  A couple comments in the earlier question suggested that Microsoft was being more generous with access then what was really needed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on 2K8 but on prior versions my users never have full control and have never experienced an issue because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Users need "change" permissions on the roaming profile folders located on the file server.

Change permissions are defined like this:

FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | FILE_ADD_FILE | FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY | FILE_READ_EA | FILE_WRITE_EA | FILE_TRAVERSE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES | READ_CONTROL | DELETE